# C# Transferring contents of a listbox from one form to another

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I am currently trying to send information from a list box on form 1 to form 2

The list box is populated by using buttons which adds an entry to the list box in form 1, I want the system to then transfer these items between the forms in my application by transferring the items that are present in the listbox in form 1 to the listbox in form 2. form 2 can then add items to its listbox in the same way via buttons and send the updated information in the list box back.

My idea is that i need to record the information in the listbox before changing from form 1 to form 2, and then once form 2 opens, the information that is saved from form 1 is then added to the listbox in form 2. However, to say im new to coding is an understatement so i have no idea how to do this. Any help you can provide is appreciated.
Regards,
Tom Smith

Answer (score 0):

you can just pass the listbox, then set the datasources to be equal.  You can do it in the contructor like this

from form1

```
Form2 form = new Form2(listBox1);
```

from form2

```
public Form2(listbox box)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listbox1.datasource = box.datasource;
}
```

Just make sure to call initializeComponent() first, otherwise you will get errors because listbox1 wont exist yet.

If Form2 is already created make a method in form2 to set it from form1

from form1

```
form.setListBoxDataSource(listBox1); //form = an instance of form2
```

from form2

```
public void setListBoxDataSource(listBox1 box)
{
    listbox1.datasource = box.datasource;
}
```

It's important to note, for this to work you would need to add the items to your first listbox from a datasource such as a list.  If you are using listBox1.Item.Add("something"),  You will have to iterate through the listbox items, add them to a list, pass the list and set the list as the datasource for list 2.  Like you were saying.

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts that will help write better software.

First it is often better to maintain data outside of forms. .Net programmers are lead by Visual Studio to keep data in forms. This is however not done using databases such as when using Entity Framework. When not using databases it is a good idea to have our data separate anyway.

Another point is that it is better to create an object to maintain the data separately from the control and to bind the control(s) to that data source.

To create a sample of this just create a forms application and add a second form.

I am not sure how you will be displaying Form2 relative to Form1 but for the purposes of my sample I will display Form2 after Form1 (from Main) in the following manner:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

In the Program class add the following:

```
static public BindingList<String> Items = new BindingList<String>();
```

That creates a list of strings. Note that I am making it a static but there are other possibilities, I do not know what your relevant requirements are. To use BindingList you need the following "using";

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

I am assuming that since you want Form2's data to be added after Form1's data that you actually can use just one list. If you need two lists then it is easy enough to create two.

Then in the form's constructor add (after InitializeComponent):

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
listBox1.DataSource = Program.Items;
```

I am not sure what "list box is populated by using buttons" means but I assume you did not explain that because that is irrelevant. For my sample I am generating data using DateTime. So in the button's click event do "Program.Items.Add" as in the following:

```
Program.Items.Add("1 "+DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss.ff"));
```

That will add an item to the Items. The data of course is whatever data your application needs. The new addition will show in the ListBox. I have "1" there because for Form2 I use "2". Otherwise the code for Form is the same for my sample.

I hope that describes the code adequately. I can post more of it if this is not clear.